# Get all possibles pos tags from a single word

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm currently trying to get all possible pos tags of a single word using Python. 
From traditional pos taggers you get back only one tag, if you enter the single word.
Is there a way to get all possiblities?
Is it possible to search in a corpora(e.g. brown) for a specific word and not just for a category?

Kind regards & thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `pos_tag()` using this approach - specifically for `brown`,

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

# x is a dict which will have the word as key and pos tags as values 
x = defaultdict(list)

# looping for first 100 words and its pos tags
for word, pos in brown.tagged_words()[1:100]:
    if pos not in x[word]:        # to append one tag only once
        x[word].append(pos)       # adding key-value to x

# to print the pos tags for the word 'further'
print(x['further'])
#['RBR']
```

Comment: Is this method reliable? It outputs `['VB', 'NN', 'VBN', 'VBD']` for "run" (after removing the first 100 words `[1:100]` constraint).

Comment: Identification of possible POS tags for a given word is a common requirement for advanced NLP (such as when building a POS tagger), and they should provide a function for this.